# Use createView with allowDiskUse

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In the mongo aggregation framework is possible to use the option `{allowDiskUse:true}`. This is really useful when some heavy operations such as sorting, which cannot be performed in memory.

I'm trying to do the same with `createView` (available in Mongo 3.4), but I cannot find the place where `allowDiskUse` can be introduced.

In the normal aggregation framework:

```
db.mydb.aggregate([....,{$sort:{"a":-1}}],{allowDiskUse:true})
```

works, but:

```
db.createView("newview","mydb",[....,{$sort:{"a":-1}}],{allowDiskUse:true})
```

produces the error

```
The field 'allowDiskUse' is not a valid collection option.
```

Of course, I can just remove `{allowDiskUse:true}`. Then the view is created, but when I try:

```
> db.newview.find()
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.",
    "code" : 16819,
    "codeName" : "Location16819"
}
```

How to create a view that include large operations?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `allowDiskUse` when creating a view because it is not a [`create`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/create/#dbcmd.create)  option. Actually the only supported option is the [`collation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) option also new in version 3.4

One way to get around this to pass `allowDiskUse` to your aggregation query, use the `$out` option to write your aggregation result to a new collection and create your view on the newly created collection.

But the view created this way will not have any value because you will need to recreated the new collection with `$out` every time before querying the view.

Another workaround is to performing an aggregation on the view and pass in the `allowDiskUse` option as mentioned on this [closed JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27440)

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use $out then the view becomes almost useless

Comment: Exactly that is what I mentioned in the last sentence. Perhaps you should consider to create an issue on Jira and link it to this question

Comment: Not as ideal as a realtime collection, but this workaround does the trick for generating a collection from an large aggregation.

Then you can use `mongoexport` to export the data into JSON for further processing.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone finds the same problem, Kyle Suarez at jira proposed the following workaround:

```
 db.newview.aggregate([], { allowDiskUse: true });
```

that is, using an aggregation on the view solves the problem.