# Query over MongoDB views failing with reason exceed memory restriction

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We can pass `allowDiskUse: true` in `MongoDB` aggregation. But If we are running query on a view created with same aggregation pipeline, there is no option to pass `allowDiskUse: true`. Consequently , view is getting created without any problem, but query is giving error regarding memory usage exceeds 100 MB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use createView with allowDiskUse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149573/use-createview-with-allowdiskuse)

Comment: Also if possible try to optimize the query.